# Deletion of .kibana indices in opensearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

In each new version of opensearch, the .kibana of each user is duplicated, for example, for the admin user I have the following indices:

green open .kibana_92668751_admin_1 YWvTNdScTh26CfqM7FABSA 1 0 3 0 17.2kb 17.2kb

green open .kibana_92668751_admin_3 ELmp_GlxRq6zMAOX8U23LA 1 0 4 0 22.6kb 22.6kb

green open .kibana_92668751_admin_2 1faLD4EPRwajc9–LIBX2A 1 0 3 0 17.2kb 17.2kb

green open .kibana_92668751_admin_4 X7OWpreHRM-1HIMbqrKbvg 1

I have created one dashboard and then tried deleting all .kibana indices (even the latest one) for me and after that everything seems to be working alright and even the dashboard is still persisting.
I want to know why this is happening that even after deleting the .kibana indices for a user, the data like dashboard and visualization is still persisting.

Also is there a way/dsl query I can use to delete .kibana indices based on creation.date metadata so that I can delete my old .kibana indices in one go every time I update to a new version.

Thank you in advance!

I have created one dashboard and then tried deleting all .kibana indices (even the latest one) for me and after that everything seems to be working alright and even the dashboard is still persisting.